# Issues extracting Streamlink Twitch GUI Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, software-installation, tar

I am a bit new to Ubuntu Unity here, and I'm having issues extracting the streamlink-twitch-gui file.  I've followed the [instructions](https://github.com/streamlink/streamlink-twitch-gui/wiki/Installation#linux-1) to put in in a tmp folder, but when I try to execute:

```
sudo tar -xzvf /tmp/streamlink-twitch-gui.tar.gz -C /opt
```

It comes back with:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar; Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I'm not sure why it isn't working; I double-checked my downloaded file, re-started my xterm and re-wrote the code, tried some other variations of the line like using xjf and xvf instead of -xzvf, and including the archive download url, but nothing.  Any help you could give me would be fantastic.

Comment: Remove the `z` option from the tar command. It seems like maybe your browser already decompressed it when saving the file.

Comment: Straight command line works well enough although I am not entirely clear exactly which archive you are after. This worked on my system: `wget --content-disposition https://github.com/streamlink/streamlink-twitch-gui/archive/v1.3.1.tar.gz && sudo tar xvf streamlink-twitch-gui-1.3.1.tar.gz -C /opt`. (This example downloads source code only not a compiled binary...)

Comment: I tried both of the options suggested and it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: @PaulKearney The command line I suggested is a single command that can be copied and pasted in one piece into  Terminal window. Works perfectly here. If you can tell me if you are running 64 or 32 bit Ubuntu I can write up a full answer that should get it all running.